# Can I set the default value for future inserts differently than the default value for current records?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I am looking to alter an SQL table by creating a record added Col. With this I want the future records added to default to NOW(). I tried:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN recordCreated DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NOW()
```

But this caused the current records to receive the datetime of when the script was run. I am looking to see if I can set the default of the current records to null and the future records to NOW.

I know that I could do this by running an Update to set the Col values to null afterwards but I'd rather avoid doing this.

Is there anyway to leave the current records null?

Tried:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN recordCreated DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NOW()
```

Expected:
recoredCreated Col for preexisting records to be null and all new records to be NOW()

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server; what RDBMS are you *really* using? DDL syntax is can often be dialect specific.

Comment: Don't add *"Edit: Mysql 5.7.12"* to your question, fix your tags. I have done this for you, by adding the version tag, the sql tag, and removed the incorrect [[tag:sql-server]] tag.

Comment: There's a good answer here on how to acocomplish this without an UPDATE [Add new column with default value, not for existing rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221435/add-new-column-with-default-value-not-for-existing-rows) Basically you add the column without `DEFAULT` and then modify the column to add the `DEFAULT` as a second step. Perhaps 6-of-1/half-a-dozen-of-the-other, but I like it better than then `MODIFY + UPDATE` route.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life next year. Maybe you should be upgrading soon.